# convert c++ map to jobject JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I want to transfer a C++ map to Java and have no idea how to define the return parameter so the method works. I had no trouble with string or int as return parameters, but i can´t get map working.
My Java method looks like this:

```
private native Map<String,String> sayHello();
```

My C++ Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include "HelloJNI.h"
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello
(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
    map<string, string> mMap;
    mMap["1"] = "Ladi";
    mMap["2"] = "Dida";
    return mMap;
}
```

And of course i get an error, telling me i have to convert mMap to jobject somehow. But i have no idea how to do this.

I hope its no double-post, i just found some questions dealing with transmitting lists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An independent issue, but one that would be in any implementation of your method, is which character encoding do the strings in `mMap` use. Code using `.c_str()` assumes that the data contains no NUL characters. And code using `NewStringUTF` assumes that the encoding (or a least as far as the expected data goes) is interpretable as _modified_ UTF-8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use jni api to find `HashMap` java class, then its methods for construction and insertion of elements. Then Add all the elements and finally return this map. It should look as follows (warning - pseudocode !!!)

```
env->PushLocalFrame(256); // fix for local references

jclass hashMapClass= env->FindClass(env, "java/util/HashMap");
jmethodID hashMapInit = env->GetMethodID(env, hashMapClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject hashMapObj = env->NewObject(env, hashMapClass, hashMapInit, mMap.size());
jmethodID hashMapOut = env->GetMethodID(env, hashMapClass, "put",
            "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

for (auto it : mMap)
{
    env->CallObjectMethod(env, hashMap, put,
         env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str()),
         env->NewStringUTF(it->second.c_str()));
}

env->PopLocalFrame(hashMap);

return hashMap;
```

ps. I usually code jni under android, but above code should work the same under other platforms.

Comment: Nice.  But I'd think it would be easier to simply pass an empty `HashMap` object to the native code and call the `put` method on it, like `private native void sayHello( Map<String,String> jmap );`

Comment: @mrtnj thanks for your quick answer. I ll give it a try today and let you know if i could get it going :)
AndrewHenle thats a nice idea, and i think it would be definitely easier as the other solution but the problem is in my programm the map has to be filled with values before the native java function is called. But thanks anyway mate!

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes. It is often less error prone to move some JNI stuff back to Java. `private native` methods are the way to go. `public` methods should should have a natural Java interface, though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I would pass HashMap instance from java to jni if I would like to add additional elements to existing instance, or I would like to limit creation of multiple HashMap instances (ie. I would call this function in a loop) as a memory optimization. Otherwise creating HashMap in jni seems to be fine.

Comment: What is `PopLocalFrame` function?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko PushLocalFrame/PopLocalFrame allows you to create a new scope of local references. For example, PushLocalFrame(32) creates a frame where you might create at most 32 local references (always check its return value!), then PopLocalFrame(NULL) will release all those references, returning to the previous reference frame (in a stack manner). Its useful if you have a loop where you must allocate local references but on each iteration you release them.

Comment: ....So instead of calling multiple times DeleteLocalRef on each local reference on each iteration, you call PopLocalFrame(NULL) once. If you use C++ then you may put Push/Pop local frame calls in a RAII style class, ensuring there will be no local ref. leaks.

Comment: Thanks! About RAII your are right, will fix. But also if I understood correctly if I have loop for 1000 iteractions and in each one I call let's say `NewStringUTF`, so it mean that I have to call `PushLocalFrame(1000)`, right?

Comment: By default there is a limit for only 16 local references, to make sure you will not exceed it you should either call PushLocalFrame or EnsureLocalCapacity.  If you need to use those 1000 local references after your loop ends, then you should ensure capacity is enough So you may call PushLocalFrame(1000) and PopLocalFrame(NULL) after the loop and after you make use of those strings. If the result of NewStringUTF is used only inside one loop iteration then you may as well call DeleteLocalRef on it, or inside the inner loop block call Push/Pop local frame.